# How to convert angle and magnitude into horizontal and vertical components?

Tags: javascript

I need to convert between angle/magnitude and horizontal/vertical components.

These formulas come closest to working but are somewhat glitchy:

```
function velocityToSpeeds(direction, speed) {
  return {
    hspeed: -speed*Math.sin(Math.toRad(direction) - 90) + 0, 
    vspeed: -speed*Math.cos(Math.toRad(direction) - 90) + 0
  };
}

function velocityToSpeedsALTERNATIVE(direction, speed) {
  return {
    x: speed*Math.cos(Math.toRad(direction)), 
    y: speed*Math.sin(Math.toRad(direction))
  };
}

function speedsToVelocity(hspeed, vspeed) {
  return {
    direction: Math.round(Math.toDeg(Math.atan2(vspeed, hspeed))) + 0,
    speed: Math.round(Math.sqrt(hspeed * hspeed + vspeed * vspeed)) + 0
  }
}`
```

The `+0` is to stop the function from returning `-0`.

I'm using screen coordinates; e.g. (0,0) is top left.  Also, 0 degrees is to the right, and 270 degrees is down.  So if I convert a horizontal speed (hspeed) of 1 and vertical speed (vspeed) of 0 to angle and magnitude, I should get 0 degrees (direction), 1 magnitude (speed).

`speedsToVelocity(1, 0)` works correctly.

But `speedsToVelocity(0, 1)` returns 90 degrees, 1 speed when the angle should be 270 degrees.

There are other problems with these formulas also, but they are the best I've got.  Please don't point me to any other questions/answers; I assure you, if it exists on the internet I have tried it already and found it doesn't work either.  I've built up quite a collection of vector functions over the past 3 days supposed to do what I need but none work.

Comment: Why are all of your functions dense, unreadable, magical one-liners? They don't even work yet.

Comment: It's a math problem. Write out your variables and constants with names. Take as many lines as you need to. Use `console.log` or a debugger to output the results of every operation. At some step, you'll get an unexpected result. That's the bug in your formula.

Comment: @AndrewKoster I forgot to delete all the possibly superfluous `Number()` I inserted while debugging, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work with these modifications:

```
function velocityToSpeeds(direction, speed) {
  return {
    hspeed: Number(-Number(speed)*Math.sin(Math.toRad(Number(direction) - 90))) + 0, 
    vspeed: Number(-Number(speed)*Math.cos(Math.toRad(Number(direction) - 90))) + 0
  };
}

function speedsToVelocity(hspeed, vspeed) {
  return {
    direction: Math.round(Number(Math.toDeg(Math.atan2(Number(vspeed), Number(hspeed))))) + 0,
    speed: Math.round(Number(Math.sqrt(Number(hspeed) * Number(hspeed) + Number(vspeed) * Number(vspeed)))) + 0
  }
}
```

Here are a couple more as a bonus:

```
function negativeHspeed(direction) {
  return ((180 - direction) + 360) % 360;
}

function negativeVspeed(direction) {
    return 360 - direction;
}
```